# Elm get raw JSON string

Tags: elm

I'm trying to build a very simple app that will just output the raw JSON object from an api.

So I want a function that will take a url parameter and ideally return the JSON string.

I have the following code:

```
decode: String -> String
decode jsonString =
  Decode.decodeString jsonString

apiResonse : String -> String
apiResonse url =
  let
    url = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&tag=cats"
    request = Http.get Decode.decodeString url
  in
    Http.send NewRequest request
```

But I'm struggling to understand the decoder part of the function. If anyone could help me that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to get the HTTP response as a string value, use [`Http.getString`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#getString). The example you posted using `Http.get` assumes the result is in JSON and forces you to decode it to an Elm value.

Here is a modified example of the [random cat generator](http://elm-lang.org/examples/http) code which just displays a dump of the response JSON instead of a cat picture:

```elm
getRandomGif : String -> Cmd Msg
getRandomGif topic =
  let
    url =
      "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&tag=" ++ topic
  in
    Http.send NewGif (Http.getString url)
```

Here is a [working example on ellie-app.com](https://ellie-app.com/49g4dpFrPDVa1/0)